# how to get sum on every loop on the table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem on breaking down the amount of the given payment, I think i was missing something on my code. This is my table below.

If i have payment of 5,000, it will deduct on the first row and the remaining sum will send to the 2nd row.

//this is the payment

```
$payment = 5000;
$temp = '';
```

//the loop of function

```
$data = payment_breakdown();
foreach ($data as $row) {

    $amount = $row['AMOUNT'] - $payment."\n";
}
```

//handle the difference of every loop of the function

```
$temp = $amount;
```

//result of the amount

```
echo $amount;
```

//this is my function to get the data from the table

```
function payment_breakdown(){
    $db = database2();
    $query = "SELECT AMOUNT FROM TABLE1";
    $cmd = $db->prepare($query);    
    $cmd->execute();
    $rows = $cmd->fetchAll();
    $db = null;

    return $rows;
}
```

supposedly if the amount on the table is this

```
Data From Table | The Payment
        3000    |     3000
        3000    |     2000
```

Comment: Hmm, can you elaborate more what is the question? Is `The Payment` column inserts wrong data?

Comment: You might mean `$temp += $amount;`

Comment: the problem is you're mixing the actual difference (the arithmetic itself) and the presentation, concatenate the newline string character on the echo, not on the temporary variable where you make the arithmetic. it mixes up your datatypes. separate `$amount = $row['AMOUNT'] - $payment` and this `echo $amount . "\n"`.

Comment: @Roshan Hi sir, the payment column was correct, supposed to be if I have 5000, it will deduct on the first row and the remaining sum will send to the 2nd row.

Comment: and probably add an `abs()` function so that you won't have a negative value

Comment: Can you specify sum of `data from table` or `payment`?

Comment: `$sum += $amount = $row['AMOUNT'] - $payment;  $amount .= "\n";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in SQL:

```
SELECT 
  amount, 
  paid,
  sum(amount-paid) open
FROM
  payment 
GROUP BY amount, paid 
WITH ROLLUP
HAVING 
  amount IS NULL
  OR paid IS NOT NULL
;
```

Based on the data

```
INSERT INTO payment (amount, paid)
VALUES 
(3000,3000), 
(3000,2000),
(4000,1000)
;
```

you get

```
amount;paid; open
3000  ;2000; 1000
3000  ;3000; 0
4000  ;1000; 3000
NULL  ;NULL; 4000
```

Or you might want a simple substraction from a deposit:

```
SET @credit := 5000;

SELECT 
  amount, 
  @credit := @credit-amount credit  
FROM payment 
;

SELECT @credit;
```

However, in the latter case you should rather store all payments and amounts to pay into database tables and sum up all together. Consider refactoring your database structure design.

Comment: I actually used php